# SQL Inner Query WHERE clause access to Outer Query tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning -

This is my first post here, after many years using SO as a very useful resource.

I've run into a problem with a complex (for me) query I'm pulling together for a wordpress site running woocommerce to process orders. I'm trying to add a filter to the order list which filters orders which contain products in a particular product category.

I'm afraid I've gotten in over my head with this query which joins a variety of meta tables on inner queries in order to get at the information I need in order to determine the product's category.

The problem is that I can't get the scoping rules to work in order to access required outer table information in the inner queries.

The query is:

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        wp_ot6q6i_posts.ID
    FROM
        wp_ot6q6i_posts
    WHERE
        1 = 1 AND YEAR(wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_date) = 2015 AND MONTH(wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_date) = 12 AND wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_type = 'shop_order' AND(
            (
                wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-pending' OR wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-processing' OR wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-on-hold' OR wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-completed' OR wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-cancelled' OR wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-refunded' OR wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_status = 'wc-failed'
            )
        ) AND EXISTS(
        SELECT
            t2.PROD_ID
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value AS PROD_ID
            FROM
                wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_items
            LEFT JOIN
                wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
            ON
                wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
            WHERE
                wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item' AND wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id' AND wp_ot6q6i_posts.ID = wp_ot6q6i_woocommerce_order_items.order_id
        ) t1
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            wposts.ID AS PROD_ID
        FROM
            wp_ot6q6i_posts wposts
        LEFT JOIN
            wp_ot6q6i_postmeta wpostmeta
        ON
            wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
        LEFT JOIN
            wp_ot6q6i_term_relationships
        ON
            (
                wposts.ID = wp_ot6q6i_term_relationships.object_id
            )
        LEFT JOIN
            wp_ot6q6i_term_taxonomy
        ON
            (
                wp_ot6q6i_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_ot6q6i_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
            )
        WHERE
            wp_ot6q6i_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND wp_ot6q6i_term_taxonomy.term_id IN(
            SELECT
                term_id
            FROM
                `wp_ot6q6i_terms`
            WHERE
                slug = 'preorder'
        )
    ORDER BY
        wpostmeta.meta_value
    ) t2
    ON
        t1.PROD_ID = t2.PROD_ID
    )
    ORDER BY
        wp_ot6q6i_posts.post_date
    DESC
    LIMIT 0, 20
```

And the error I'm getting is:

1054 - Unknown column 'wp_ot6q6i_posts.ID' in 'where clause'

Comment: Please the table schema for wp_ot6q6i_posts?

Comment: @DaniloBustos - thanks for your help. The error actually comes from the previous `SELECT` before wposts is defined...just to be clear, that `WHERE` needs to be filtered on the outermost `wp_ot6q6i_posts.ID` - which corresponds to the order number.

Comment: @GurV - https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts

Comment: One word: table aliases (ok, two words)

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, note that `LEFT JOIN tt.. WHERE tt... = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN tt`

Comment: And ORDER BY clauses within a subquery are generally meaningless.

Comment: You really should hang out here more often

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Strawberry...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. I ended up going in a different direction to solve this problem, one I'm more comfortable with as a dev...I'm pulling the fixed list of items from the last join and building a query in code that has a series of more simple queries in the where clause, thereby avoiding the whole Exists approach.

Thanks again for your help.